# Getting exception "Not using JDBC" while using quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache with quarkus-reactive-mysql-client - (Quarkus 1.12.2.Final)

Tags: quarkus

**Quarkus 1.12.2.Final**

Getting the following exception while using *reactive hibernate* (quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache) with *reactive MySQL client* (quarkus-reactive-mysql-client), kindly suggests what could be the issue.

```
2021-04-01 11:35:28,694 ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Quarkus Main Thread) Not using JDBC
2021-04-01 11:35:28,727 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): java.sql.SQLException: Not using JDBC
    at org.hibernate.reactive.provider.service.NoJdbcConnectionProvider.getConnection(NoJdbcConnectionProvider.java:25)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
```

**Some details**

*My application.properties*

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=root
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
quarkus.datasource.reactive.max-size=20
```

*My Repository Implementation*

```
@ApplicationScoped public class EventRepository implements PanacheRepository<Event> {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The latest version available of Hibernate Reactive doesn't support schema update and validation yet."

Relative issue here:

- [Not using JDBC problem met in native build · Issue #19918 · quarkusio/quarkus · GitHub](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19918)

Answer (score 3):

Change your `application.properties` to

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=root
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=vertx-reactive:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
quarkus.datasource.reactive.max-size=20
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the cause of the problem -> I used property **"quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update"**. It seems like the use of this property requires JDBC connection, removed it, and it's working fine.

Any of the below config sets can work.

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.username=****
quarkus.datasource.password=****
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=mysql://localhost:3306/db
or 
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=vertx-reactive:mysql://localhost:3306/db
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the following property to your settings?

`quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update`

You can write `drop-and-create` to re-create your db when you run your server as well. See details [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. **JDBC** and **Hibernate update** should work in your case. Do you have a **JDBC extension (dependency)**  in your project? If not, try to ad one.

In case of a postgres you can add extension this way:

```
./mvnw quarkus:add-extension -Dextensions="jdbc-postgresql
```

More info here

> Add the agroal extension plus one of jdbc-db2, jdbc-derby, jdbc-h2, jdbc-mariadb, jdbc-mssql, jdbc-mysql, jdbc-oracle or jdbc-postgresql.
>
> https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to your `pom.xml` file.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-jdbc-mysql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And also remove from your `application.properties` following line:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you explicitly disabled JDBC

Remove `quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false`  from your applications.properties.

More details https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#reactive-connection-pool-size-adjustment